# WordPress duplicating but same login

Tags: php, wordpress, duplicates

I've duplicated my own site to another domain and I want to run both the websites. I am confused between the same login for both the sites. The one which I copied is www.artiana.io and the one which I copied to is www.teamnautilus.com, the WordPress login for both are same. I am scared to make any further changes as it may affect both the sites. Please, can anyone clear my doubt?

Best regards,
Sahaba

Comment: Don't worry! Changes will be occure there only, where you'll do.

Comment: ok, thanks. But I can also not access the customize page. :( @ankit

Comment: I cannot even open the plugin page. I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will create  anew databse and import your first one to new databse and then connect 2nd setup with newly created databse.
In this way you have two diffrent sites with diffrent databse